# How to automatic add the first line of text from a list box to a text box

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

Right I have got a list box which contains a list of tracks and when the track is pressed it moves to a second list box, what I now need to happen is have the first item that's in the second list box move automatic to a text box.

This is my current code for the first move

```
private void genreListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   playlistListBox.Items.Add(genreListBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

I am thinking it should be something like this

```
presentlyPlayingTextBox.AppendText(playlistListBox.);
```

But I'm not sure how to add the first line without clicking it.

I have tried this but I get an error for the value.

```
presentlyPlayingTextBox.Text = playlistListBox.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use something like the 'SelectedIndexChanged' or 'SelectedValueChanged' action of a listbox, otherwise events like DoubleClick will fail if the keyboard is used to change the selection.

Also that event should be triggered on the second listbox when it is changed by the first.

EDIT:

On a standard Listbox, there is no .SelectedItem.Value, only .SelectedItem.
However as a listbox holds objects, not just text, you need to say you want the text value.

```
presentlyPlayingTextBox.Text = playlistListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: For my assignment it says the double click event that's why I used it, and I still have no answer to how I display the first line from a list box into a text box. I have edited the question with my latest attempt

Comment: I have updated my answer with what may be your problem.

Comment: This still requires the item to be clicked for the second move I need it to move as soon as an item is moved into the first position/indices

Comment: You need to either make the Listbox1 doubleclick action update both Listbox2 and the Textbox, or setup the SelectedIndexChanged on Listbox2 to update the Textbox.  On the right side tooolbox where you normally set the properties of a control, look for the lightning tab which lists the actions and allows you to double click on them to create code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, but if you're just attempting to move the first item from ListBox_2 to a textbox, would the following work?

```
presentlyPlayingTextBox.Text = playlistListBox.Items[0]?.Value; // C# >= 6
presentlyPLayingTextBox.Text = ((playlistListBox.Items == null) ? playlistListBox.Items[0].Value : "" ); // C# < 6
```

You could also create your own delegate/event that would fire when the user did some action.